# String to array, then select check boxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery question. I currently store some data in a mysql table which is delimited by commas. Here is an example of the data stored

> Tbl_stage " concept , prerevenue , 10mm , 20mm "

Once I echo this data in php, I need each check box to be checked if it is contained in the array

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="check-item" class="primary1" checked /> concept </label> 
<label><input type="checkbox" id="check-item" class="primary1" checked /> pre-revenue </label> 
<label><input type="checkbox" id="check-item" class="primary1" /> sample blank data </label>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why `prerevenue` is without `-` ?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried to do: question is too broad as it stands. Have you got the info from mySQl? Do you need help exploding the data into an array you can iterate? How are you outputting the HTML (in variable, from template)? Put some code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First of all prepare an `array` without any spaces around the `string`.
- Filter `checkbox` elements by testing `text` of label with `array` of `trimmed` values retrieved from `DB`.
- Use `jQuery.prop(PROPERTY, STATE)` to set `checked` property.

```js
var str = " concept , prerevenue , 10mm , 20mm ";
var arr = str.split(' , ').map(function(el) {
  return el.trim();
});
$('.primary1').filter(function() {
  return (arr.indexOf($(this).closest('label').text().replace('-', '').trim()) !== -1);
}).prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-item" class="primary1" />concept</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-item" class="primary1" />pre-revenue</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-item" class="primary1" />sample blank data</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the data from table using query and push each element into an array.
Then use the array to check each data and echo checked in your checkbox tag

```
<?php 
  $query = 'Your query here to get the data from database table';
  $results = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
  {
     $results[] = $row;
  }
?>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-item" class="primary1" <?php if(in_array("concept",$results)) echo "checked";?> /> concept </label> 
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-item" class="primary1" <?php if(in_array("pre-revenue",$results)) echo "checked";?> /> pre-revenue </label> 
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-item" class="primary1" <?php if(in_array("sample blank data",$results)) echo "checked";?> /> sample blank data </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

We have split function in js 
ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Split the string that you get from the server.It will be array of words
for example

```
var str = "concept , prerevenue , 10mm , 20mm";
var res = str.split(",");
```

Then you will get array with values 
concept
prerevenue
10mm
20mm

You can loop it and set the checked value to true

```
$("input[type=checkbox][value=res[i]").attr("checked","true");
```

and don't forget to put values of input values same as the label values

ref:http://jsfiddle.net/LCU4C/2/

Answer (score 1):

Update your script as follows:

```
<?php
$arr = array("concept" , "prerevenue" , "10mm" , "20mm"); ?>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="check-item" class="primary1" <?php echo in_array("concept",$arr) ? "checked" : "" ?> /> concept </label> 
<label><input type="checkbox" id="check-item" class="primary1" <?php echo in_array("prerevenue",$arr) ? "checked" : "" ?> /> prerevenue </label>
```